# Laravel auth and "subdomains"

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm using Laravel 5x and I'm trying to have the user login from (for example):

https://dev.example.com/example_authentication/public/login (this is one instance of laravel)

and then when I access:

https://dev.example.com/mysecondwebsite/public (this is another instance of laravel) I can just call:

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

and then get if its a user, admin, its name, etc.

What I've tried is to add both  on the .env file of example_authentication and mysecondwebsite

```
SESSION_DOMAIN='.example.com'
```

but the session does not persist.

any idea on what's happening?

UPDATE:

I'm using on the second laravel app

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

for some reason it's generating its own session, for the record both instances have the same:

```
 'cookie' => 'vanguard_session'
  the same APP_KEY
  the same SESSION_DRIVER
```

Comment: Those sites aren't subdomains, they are on the same domain name under a different folder. So they are on the same session. of course if they uise different databases, then it might not find the user and the app breaks or something, or acts weirdly and pulls out a different user. something like that?  its not clear whether you mean to share or separate sessions

Comment: @delboy1978uk I meant to share the session, remember that both sites are 2 instances of laravel, one is:

https://dev.example.com/example_authentication/public/

and the other is

https://dev.example.com/mysecondwebsite/public 

I want the user to log in first on the first one and get all the session info on the second but haven't had any luck yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't integrate the first project session to the latter but found an alternative with the `$_SESSION` variable:

if you want to have this variable working for both projects you have to set `session_start();` on public/index.php on both projects.

```
<?php
session_start();
```

after that you can use the $_SESSION variable on every controller and this will show on any PHP web app you have on your server, I wanted to use the traditional way of laravel but had no luck and there isn't much info about this requirement, so here's the alternative.

You can use this variable like this inside any controller,view or middleware:

```
$_SESSION["setyourvarname"]="your value";
```

then on the controller, view or middleware you can just

```
$myvariable = $_SESSION["myvarname"]
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Laravel uses file based session storage. For this you might need to look at database session storage or something else: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session#configuration

Also for this to work the user will need to exist in both Laravel applications, are they sharing the same database?

Comment: Yeah both are using the database session storage, both have the same keys, same cookie name and same app name, they are just in different folders and are different projects